# I can't transfer my class variable into another class

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Really desperate to ask this. I need to transfer my CipherText into another class, and it doesn't work. What am I missing? Sorry for the long post. (I've already removed the some GUI(tkinter) codes in those 2 class.) I can't seem to find solutions here. Would Gladly appreciate for some help. Thanks!!!

```
class Decmesbuttons():


   def decmescommand(self):
       datenow = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
       timenow = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())


       privk = privkeyvarS.get()

       #No key found error
       try:
           pathpriv = r'/home/gene/Desktop/ppl/keys/' + privk
           loadprivkey = M2Crypto.RSA.load_key (pathpriv + '/' + privk + '-private.key')

       except IOError: 
           tkMessageBox.showwarning("Warning!", "No "+ privk + " key found.")


       #Wrong key error & printing of the decrypted message
       try:
           PlainText = loadprivkey.private_decrypt (Ciphertext, M2Crypto.RSA.pkcs1_oaep_padding)

           if PlainText != "":
               tkMessageBox.showinfo("DECRYPTED!","Message decrypted by " + privk + " :" + Plaintext)

       except:
           tkMessageBox.showwarning("Warning!", "Wrong key!")

class Encmesbuttons():


    def encmescommand(self):
        datenow = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
        timenow = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())

        m = messagevarS.get()
        pk = pubkeyvarS.get()

        #Input of selected message to encrypt

        em = m + '\n' + '-'
        if not m:
            tkMessageBox.showwarning("Warning!", "No message to encrypt")

        else:
            #add to log
            logkey = open ('log'+datenow+'.txt', 'a')
            logkey.write(timenow +'-'  + ' Some user inputted a message.' + "\n") 
            logkey.close()

            f = open ('message.txt', 'w')
            f.write(str(m)) 
            f.close()

        try:
            #select the public key owner to send your encrypted message 

            pathpub = r'/home/gene/Desktop/ppl/keys/' + pk
            loadpub = M2Crypto.RSA.load_pub_key (pathpub+ '/' + pk + '-public.key')

            global CT
            CipherText = loadpub.public_encrypt (m, M2Crypto.RSA.pkcs1_oaep_padding)
            CT = CipherText

            #Print the ciphered message

            tkMessageBox.showinfo("The encrypted message",str(CipherText.encode('base64')))

            #write ciphered text to file
            f = open ('encryption.txt', 'w')
            f.write(str(CipherText.encode ('base64')))
            f.close()

            #add to log
            logkey = open ('log'+datenow+'.txt', 'a')
            logkey.write(timenow +'-' + 'Some user has encrypted the message and selected ' + pk + ' as the receiver' +  "\n") 
            logkey.close()


        except IOError: 
            tkMessageBox.showwarning("Warning!", "No public key inputted")
```

I need this variable:

```
CipherText = loadpub.public_encrypt (m, M2Crypto.RSA.pkcs1_oaep_padding)
```

to be in this line (the one with the Here sign):

```
 PlainText = loadprivkey.private_decrypt (**HERE**, M2Crypto.RSA.pkcs1_oaep_padding)
```

Comment: can't you do `def decmescommand(self, CipherText):` ? Or use `self.CipherText` and it will be accesible outside class as `some_instance.CipherText`

Comment: @furas This error shows when I do the first one you said `TypeError: decmescommand() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) `
If i use the `self.Ciphertext` like you said, It still didn't decrypt my message. Sorry for being a newb

Comment: you have to define function with argument `def decmescommand(self, txt):` and later use it with argument `some_imstance.decmescommand(CipherText)`. You should have to show how you use both classes - how and where you create instances.  Maybe then it would be easier to resolve problem.

Comment: it is not preferred but you can use `global CipherText` instead of `global CT` and your variable will be accessible in all places. Currently variable `CT` have you `CipherText` and it is accessible in all places. But there is one thing: function `encmescommand()` has to be executed before `decmescommand()` to assign value to `CipherText`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your scoping.  You have `CipherText` defined inside a method.  Try taking out `CipherText` and making it a global variable in your class.  Then you will be able to access it by calling `Encmesbuttons.CipherText`.

Comment: Should I make it like this? `CT=CipherText` Damn having no sleep is really affecting my mind now.

Comment: @Bernard1009 use `global CipherText` instead of `global CT` in `encmescommand()` or use `CT` instead of `CipherText` in `decmescommand()`

Comment: @Bernard1009 first you have to show full error message (in question), second you have to show how to use both classes. `CiperText` will be accessible in `decmescommand()` only if you execute `encmescommand()` as first.

Comment: I have this `except: tkMessageBox.showwarning("Warning!", "Wrong key!")` error when no message or wrong key is in the `CipherText`. Also tried to print the `CipherText`, and it shows only blank which i guess why the warning error is showing. I've always execute the `encmescommand()` before using the `encmescommand()`.

Comment: better use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` and you will see what real problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the last suggestion! It shows that the problem is my `PlainText` typo error. I should really get some sleep now. lol. Thank you! You're a semester saver!

Answer (score 0):

It is not preferred method but you can use `global CipherText` instead of `global CT` in `decmescommand()` and your variable will be accessible in all places. Currently variable `CT` has your `CipherText` and it is accessible in all places - so you can use `CT` instead of `CipherText` inside `encmescommand()`.

There is one thing: method `encmescommand()` has to be executed before `decmescommand()` to assign value to `CipherText` / `CT`

---

**EDIT:**

see example

```
class Decmesbuttons():

    def decmescommand(self):
        print('execute decmescommand()')

        print('CipherText:', CipherText)

class Encmesbuttons():


    def encmescommand(self):
         print('execute encmescommand()')

         global CipherText

         CipherText = "hello world"

d = Decmesbuttons()
e = Encmesbuttons()

e.encmescommand() # <- you have to run it before decmescommand()
d.decmescommand()
```

result:

```
execute encmescommand()
execute decmescommand()
CipherText: hello world
```

---

**EDIT:** more prefered method

```
class Decmesbuttons():

    def decmescommand(self, text):
        print('execute decmescommand()')

        print('CipherText:', text)

class Encmesbuttons():


    def encmescommand(self):
        print('execute encmescommand()')

        CipherText = "hello world"

        return CipherText

d = Decmesbuttons()
e = Encmesbuttons()

result = e.encmescommand() # <- you have to run it before decmescommand()
d.decmescommand(result)
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, still the wrong key error still pops up. Starting to think this might be a problem in my codings..